# Swarm or Google Game Service

Tags: android

I have 2 questions here,

1. I just try to use swarm to keep highscores, but can't make it work.

`private static final int SWARM_APP_ID = 11xxxx;
 private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-9864xxxxxxxx53";`

then

```
Swarm.enableAlternativeMarketCompatability();
Swarm.init(this, SWARM_APP_ID, "204aa09edd7xxxxxxxxxxxx");
Swarm.showDashboard();
```

why the Swarm menu kept appearing when I started the game ? it seems a lot, for only a highscore.

2. I never use google game service.. should i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Swarm.showDashboard();
Swarm.showLeaderboards();
```

that's you should use... , call it when user click the highscore menu...

and of course, i don't even know if swarm still active... better use google game services